# User input to subscribe to a parse channel

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification

I need a way for the users to subscribe for certain channels. I used the example in the installation example on parse `.com` to create a channel.

```
PushService.subscribe(context"Giants",MainActivity.class);
```

Now that the channel is created I need a way for the user to select if they want to subscribe to the channel.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I believe you must  switch to IOS tag, by your code fragment.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code. It's android I'm interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. For anyone interested here is a fragment of code that will do the job right:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                  String loc = localitate.getSelectedItem().toString();
                  String str = strada.getText().toString();
                  sendFeedback (loc,str);

private void sendFeedback(String loc, String str) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
  installation.addAllUnique("channels", Arrays.asList(loc+str));
    installation.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Is there a way to subscribe a user to a channel rather than an installation ? I'm guessing an installation is on a device basis, but what if I have users logging in&out on the same device ?